# apk file turns into .txt or .zip file when i download

Tags: html, download

Hello there can someone help me why does my apk file turns into .txt or .zip file when i download it. 
here is my code

```
<a class="btn-solid-lg page-scroll" href="kusinahanglan.apk" download><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i>Download App</a>
```